# Ember.js and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ember.js

I wanted to get a definitive answer on here for later reference now that we have a stable Ember RC. A combination of the top 2 [search results](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=emberjs+google+analytics&oq=emberjs+google+analytics&gs_l=hp.3..0i10.727.727.0.1376.1.1.0.0.0.0.70.70.1.1.0...0.0...1c.2.9.psy-ab.eU_0ckbSIWY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.cGE&fp=720839aef4a154b5&biw=1274&bih=650) for `emberjs google analytics` reveals that this is a good way to do track route changes:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  routeChanged: ( ->
    return unless window._gaq
    Em.run.next ->
      page = if window.location.hash.length > 0 then window.location.hash.substring(1) else window.location.pathname
      _gaq.push(['_trackPage', page])
  ).observes('currentPath')
```

but then I also see results for using [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for single page web applications.

<strike>I haven't tested the code above yet, it takes a few hours to propagate changes to the GA dashboard.</strike> **Update**: This doesn't show up under the Content category on my Google Analytics dashboard. Neither under "Pages" or "Events".

If anyone has advice or if there's something I'm missing somewhere let me know. I can also PR a guide for the website based on the answers here.

Comment: I am on RC1 and I cannot read the property of route.url in the context of ApplicationController. Not sure if you really need to pass the url - GA should log the caller if you don't pass the page, but still - how to get the current url (not just the path component @get('currentPath')

Comment: I'm using this method since a few days and it works well. It is tracking the :id also, I'm not sure yet if that is what I want.

Comment: acidburn2k: you're right that `@get('router.url')` doesn't work inside the `Em.run.next` function. Updated question with something that works.

Comment: Does `_gaq.push(['_trackPage', page])` need to be `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', page])`?

Comment: yes. I put the solution that worked for me here: http://mehulkar.com/posts/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use _trackPageview for things that have routable URLs and _trackEvent for things that don't.

In the [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) link when they refer to "Embedded AJAX page elements". They're not meaning SPA's, but rather those cases when the URL stays the same, but some event that you wish to track happens within the page (in the case via AJAX).

There may be other cases where it makes sense to use _trackEvent, but for route transitions I'd use _trackPageview.

Comment: so is the above implementation correct? Because it doesn't seem to be tracking anything for me. the computed property is firing.

Comment: No, the first parameter needs to be _trackPageview. Sorry I didn't catch that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Alex DiLiberto gave a really nice talk about a robust & scalable way of adding Google Analytics to an ember app in his EmberConf 2014 talk [here](http://confreaks.com/videos/3456-emberconf2014-extending-ember-with-analytics).
- [Slides](http://alexdiliberto.com/talks/extending-ember-with-analytics/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/alexdiliberto/emberconf-2014-demo)

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
     didTransition: function() {
       Ember.run.once(this, function() {
         ga('send', 'pageview', this.router.get('url'));
       });
     }
   }
});
```

The talk was aiming to be independent of which analytics library was used.

There is also now an official Ember Cookbook on implementing Google Analytics [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/adding_google_analytics_tracking/).

Answer (score 1):

Using routeChanged() is not a good way to track dynamic segments such as /category/food /category/something since it's going to be fired only once. I wrote an article about this here: http://www.randomshouting.com/2013/05/04/Ember-and-Google-Analytics.html. I also consulted with the guys behind Ember and confirmed that this is indeed the proper way to track url changes for Google Analytics.

Comment: Is there a better/different way to do this now with the [updated Router](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945)?

Comment: This was based on Ember RC3, I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it now.

There was an alternative even in RC3 where you could observe the "url" property of the router but the notification used to be fired two times each time the url changed. If that issue is fixed now then you could use that approach.

Both approaches are based on the router so there's not a lot of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers are outdated. You should be using a mixin and adding it to your Router to listen for the `didTransition` event and fire your pageview there. That way it's handled for all routes. There are several addons out there, including one I wrote called [ember tracker](https://tsteuwer.github.com/ember-tracker) which gives you `pageviews` and event tracking out-of-the-box.

You can see how I did it [here](https://github.com/tsteuwer/ember-tracker/blob/master/addon/mixins/google-analytics-route.js). It's fairly straight forward.

Comment: Do you mean to `willTransition` or `didTransition` instead of `onTransition`